# Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization - Minify files without bundling

Tags: asp.net, webforms, bundle, minify

I am using ASP.net Web Forms and I am using the Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization nuGet package for bundling/minifying css/js. Everything works fine.

However, I have some one off css/js files that I would like to minify but not bundle. Is this possible using this package? Again, I just want to simply minify the files. No need to bundle.

If so, can someone provide some example code? I can't find anything info on this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization (?). You can do it manually with an online minifier, there are lots out there.

Or use a Visual Studio extension like https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier. This one works well. Just right-click and 'Minify File'.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am looking for a way to incorporate the minification process in my build process via MSBuild. 

I guess I will need to dig into this and see how I can get something working. Ideally, I would like to minify css/js every time I perform a build.

I then need to figure out how to minify the files only when not in debug mode. I use Visual Studio so the work will be done within  Visual Studio.

Comment: Cool. Add this info to your question.